# Extra , is allowed for Destructuring assignments

Tags: javascript

In es6, the following seems to be valid code:

```
function test(a1,{a=1,b=2} = {},) {}
```

note the extra `,` in function args. I'm not sure whether this is a bug because this extra `,` is accepted only for Destructuring assignments.

Comment: It is valid in ES2017 (ES8)*, not ES6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of ES2017, a trailing comma on parameter lists is valid regardless of destructuring. (See the spec for [*FormalParameters*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#prod-FormalParameters), which specifically lists `FormalParameterList[?Yield, ?Await] ,` as one of the valid options.) For instance, this works just fine on an ES2017-compliant JavaScript engine like V8 in any recent(ish) version of Chrome:

```js
function foo(a, b,) {
  // ------------^
  console.log(a, b);
}
foo(1, 2);
```

If you're seeing an error on that comma when you're not destructuring but not when you are, it's just that the JavaScript engine you're using isn't yet quite up to the current specification (yet).

---

Similarly, a trailing comma in argument lists is also allowed in ES2017+:

```js
function foo(a, b) {
  console.log(a, b,);
  // -------------^
}
foo(1, 2);
```

Comment: Oh thanks for adding reference to the specification.